# Can the 'pciconf' command be used to identify makes and models?

Tags: freebsd, pci

Specifically, I wish to identify which model of Intel WiFi NIC is installed on my FreeBSD machine in the absence of a functioning driver. Can `pciconf` (equivalently, Linux's `lspci`) be used to easily identify such details? I can see `class`, `card` and `chip` codes upon issuing the command. Is it often that there exists some look-up table to find the model name, or is `pciconf` mostly useless for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for those on Google you will likely get some look-up tables, [for example this one](http://hodapple.com/files/pciconf.txt).

You can also try `lshal`. It's gives the most comprehensive information about installed hardware from all the tools I know on FreeBSD. It's part of `sysutils/hal`.